# How to split the result of a mysql query into multiple arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with some code. I have a MYSQL database query output that has a field value of:

```
[
 { "title":"SOC1  Certificate", "comment":"", "size":"286.845703125",
   "name":"SOC1%20Cert.pdf", "filename":"fu_iik2rfypa3tzrxh", "ext":"pdf" },
 { "title":"SOC 2 cert", "comment":"", "size":"286.845703125", 
   "name":"SOC2%20Cert.pdf", "filename":"fu_97krdbic5nrdziy", "ext":"pdf" }
]
```

What would the PHP code be to read this and split the entry into two array records?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the response contains JSON-data, so you should [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) it to an array:

```
$data = json_decode('[{ "title":"SOC1 Certificate","comment":"","size":"286.845703125","name":"SOC1%20Cert.pdf","filename":"fu_iik2rfypa3tzrxh","ext":"pdf" },{ "title":"SOC 2 cert","comment":"","size":"286.845703125","name":"SOC2%20Cert.pdf","filename":"fu_97krdbic5nrdziy","ext":"pdf" }]', true);

foreach ($data as $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $column => $value) {
        echo "{$column}: {$value}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I had spent hours but wasn't able to figure it out. Thank you very much for the code snippet. - very helpful!!